# Deploying without including node_modules on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I have a web application that is hosted on Azure App Service. When i include node_modules in the deployment package everything works fine, but I don't want to do this because of the size. After reading different articles and forum posts it was said that just including the package.json in the deployment package Azure would automatically install these packages. Deployment passes without errors, I can see in the Kudu console that the package.json is present but no node_modules. I'm bit of a novice when it comes to Azure, am I mistaken in that all my packages would be automatically installed by including package.json to the deployment package? If so, how would I best solve this problem? I don't want to go to the kudu console and manually install the packages. There seems to be mixed messages regarding this subject so I feel quite lost.

I am using github actions zip deploy to Azure if that has any effect on the behaviour of how Azure handles my deployment package.

Thanks

Comment: Sometimes it will not install the packages automatically. Did you enable build automation for ZIP deploy `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT is true` app setting? @smuckert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Need to check below to deploy a web app with* `node_modules`:

After a workaround on it, I found that including `package.json` in the deployment package of an app service doesn't automatically install packages in few situations.

However, you need to enable build automation for `ZIP deployment` by setting the `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` app setting.

You can enable it using [az webapp config appsettings set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-appsettings-set-examples) command or directly through Portal.

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps#nodejs-modules) for the information related to node.js modules and `package.json`.

Alternatively, you can also use git deployment for deploying an app service with node modules and it is clearly detailed in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment?tabs=github).

One more approach is using *zip deployment* as I mentioned in the first statement.

So I've created a sample `node js` express app by referring to [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode) and the app was successfully running as shown.

[image]

Now, I've used CLI to push the compressed node app file ([zip deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli#deploy-zip-file-with-azure-cli) ) with below given command.

```bash
az webapp deploy --resource-group <resourcegroup> --name nodeappj --src-path "/path/.../myExpressAppzip.zip"
```

[image]

*After deploying the node app to the Azure app service, I looked at the kudu console and found the node modules as shown.*

[image]